# Edit path but keep the url with http-proxy-middleware

Tags: typescript, express, reverse-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am trying to re-write path in a specific way, but can't get the result I desire, and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have the following setup:
I have `apps.eugene-dev.com` point to my server.
On my server I have several apps running on different ports, and I want to proxy to them. For example I have airflow webserver running on port 8080

I want something like this: 
`apps.eugene-dev.com/airflow` ~> `apps.eugene-dev.com:8080/` 
`apps.eugene-dev.com/airflow/some_path` ~> `apps.eugene-dev.com:8080/some_path`

But I want the url in my broweser to stay as is. So in the example above, I would get responce from `apps.eugene-dev.com:8080/some_path`, however, I would still see `apps.eugene-dev.com/airflow/some_path`.

After trying several things and not able to achive this, I am starting to question if what I want is even possible. If its not then I will have to switch to a seperate subdomain per app.

What I've tried:

This works, but this limits me to one app per subdomain

```
const airflow_target = `apps.eugene-dev.com:8080`

const airflow_proxy_options = {
    target: 'http://apps.eugene-dev.com:8080',
    logLevel: 'debug',

}


app.use('/', createProxyMiddleware(airflow_proxy_options));
```

This removes the `/airflow` from the path, but also makes the whole URL be the target url

```
const airflow_target = `apps.eugene-dev.com:8080`

const airflow_proxy_options = {
    target: 'http://apps.eugene-dev.com:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/airflow/': '',
        '^/airflow': '', // remove base path
    },

    logLevel: 'debug',

}


app.use('/airflow', createProxyMiddleware(airflow_proxy_options));
```

This keeps the URL as I want but also doesn't remove the `/airflow` hence making the request wrong (ie `...:8080/airflow/login` instead of `...:8080/login`

```
const airflow_target = `apps.eugene-dev.com:8080`

const airflow_proxy_options = {
    target: 'http://apps.eugene-dev.com:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',

}


app.use('/airflow', createProxyMiddleware(airflow_proxy_options));
```

Am I wanting too much and this is just not how it works, or is there some way to combine these effects? As I said before, I don't strictly need this to work, I have other ways to acomplish my altimate task, but it just frustrates me so much, that I think it should work but it doesn't. So hoping to learn something new.

Thank you in advance!